# How to skip a directory in awk?

Tags: awk, gawk, dir

Say I have the following structure of files and directories:

```
$ tree
.
├── a
├── b
└── dir
    └── c

1 directory, 3 files
```

That is, two files `a` and `b` together with a dir `dir`, where another file `c` stands.

I want to process all the files with `awk` (`GNU Awk 4.1.1`, exactly), so I do something like this:

```
$ gawk '{print FILENAME; nextfile}' * */*
a
b
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: command line argument `dir' is a directory: skipped
dir/c
```

All is fine but the `*` also expands to the directory `dir` and `awk` tries to process it.

So I wonder: is there any native way `awk` can check if the given element is a file or not and, if so, skip it? That is, without using `system()` for it.

I made it work by calling the external `system` in [BEGINFILE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html):

```
$ gawk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME; if (system(" [ ! -d " FILENAME " ]")) {print FILENAME, "is a dir, skipping"; nextfile}} ENDFILE{print FILENAME, FNR}' * */*
a
a 10
a.wk
a.wk 3
b
b 10
dir
dir is a dir, skipping
dir/c
dir/c 10
```

<sub>Note also the fact that `if (system(" [ ! -d " FILENAME " ]")) {print FILENAME, "is a dir, skipping"; nextfile}` works counter intuitively: it should return 1 when true, but it returns the exit code.</sub>

I read in [A.5 Extensions in gawk Not in POSIX awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/POSIX_002fGNU.html):

> - Directories on the command line produce a warning and are skipped (see [Command-line directories](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Command_002dline-directories.html#Command_002dline-directories))

And then the linked page says:

> 4.11 Directories on the Command Line
>
> According to the POSIX standard, files named on the awk command line
>   must be text files; it is a fatal error if they are not. Most versions
>   of awk treat a directory on the command line as a fatal error.
>
> By default, gawk produces a warning for a directory on the command
>   line, but otherwise ignores it. This makes it easier to use shell
>   wildcards with your awk program:
>
> ```
> $ gawk -f whizprog.awk *        Directories could kill this program
> ```
>
> If either of the --posix or --traditional options is given, then gawk
>   reverts to treating a directory on the command line as a fatal error.
>
> See [Extension Sample Readdir](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Readdir.html#Extension-Sample-Readdir), for a way to treat directories as usable
>   data from an awk program.

And in fact it is the case: the same command as before with `--posix` fails:

```
$ gawk --posix 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME; if (system(" [ ! -d " FILENAME " ]")) {print FILENAME, "is a dir, skipping"; nextfile}} ENDFILE{print FILENAME, NR}' * */*
gawk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `dir' for reading (Is a directory)
```

I checked the `16.7.6 Reading Directories` section that is linked above and they talk about `readdir`:

> The readdir extension adds an input parser for directories. The usage
>   is as follows:
>
> @load "readdir"

But I am not sure neither how to call it nor how to use it from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to safeguard your script from other people mistakenly passing a directory (or anything else that's not a readable text file) to it, you could do this:

```
$ ls -F tmp
bar  dir/  foo

$ cat tmp/foo
line 1

$ cat tmp/bar
line 1
line 2

$ cat tmp/dir
cat: tmp/dir: Is a directory

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    for (i=1;i<ARGC;i++) {
        if ( (getline line < ARGV[i]) <= 0 ) {
            print "Skipping:", ARGV[i], ERRNO
            delete ARGV[i]
        }
        close(ARGV[i])
    }
}
{ print FILENAME, $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk tmp/*
Skipping: tmp/dir Is a directory
tmp/bar line 1
tmp/bar line 2
tmp/foo line 1

$ awk --posix -f tst.awk tmp/*
Skipping: tmp/dir
tmp/bar line 1
tmp/bar line 2
tmp/foo line 1
```

Per POSIX `getline` returns `-1` if/when it fails trying to retrieve a record from a file (e.g. unreadable file or file does not exist or file is a directory), you just need GNU awk to tell you which of those failures it was by the value of `ERRNO` if you care.

Comment: Niiiice! So `getline` on a directory does not directly fail but can be handled.

Comment: RIght. When I first read your question I thought you were trying to use awk to search for files/dirs (sorry - short attention span!) but on re-reading it looks like you just want to safeguard against someone calling the script with non-file args - there's nothing wrong with doing that and above is how you do it. I've updated my answer to be a bit more supportive of that!

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is just to prevent warnings, or even exit codes, due to the fact that a dir is expanded in a supposedly just-files-list. Very interesting answer from which I learnt quite a lot, thanks : )

Answer (score 6):

I would simply avoid to pass directories to awk since even POSIX says that all filename args must be text files.

You can use `find` for traversing the directory:

```
find PATH -type f -exec awk 'program' {} +
```

Comment: Yes! I think this is the cleanest way to do it. I nevertheless wonder if `awk` can do it in any way. I edited my question because I had mistakenly used `system()`, so now it works like that, but still I don't like the fact of calling an external command for this.

Comment: @fedorqui I also played around a bit with `@load readdir` (Nice to know, thanks)..  I came to the same result, meaning using `system()` to check whether filename is a directory. I don't see a different way.

Comment: Thanks again hek! I finally accepted Ed Morton's answer since it does it in an awk way. Even though the recommendation is not to do it in general.

Comment: @fedorqui Good decision! His answer is nice!