# Remove duplicate lines by specifying more than one field, keep second sorted line

Tags: sorting, unix, awk, bioinformatics, uniq

I have a file that looks like:

```
chr1          mireap  precursor  6405246   6405544   .  -  .  ID=xxx-m0444;Count=3;mfe=-61.00
chr1          mireap  mature-5p  6405511   6405534   .  -  .  ID=xxx-m0444-5p;Parent=xxx-m044
chr1          mireap  precursor  6482110   6482198   .  +  .  ID=xxx-m0417;Count=105;mfe=-45.
chr1          mireap  mature-5p  6482123   6482143   .  +  .  ID=xxx-m0417-5p;Parent=xxx-m041
chr1          mireap  mature-3p  6482168   6482188   .  +  .  ID=xxx-m0417-3p;Parent=xxx-m041
chr1          mireap  mature-3p  6482168   6482188   .  +  .  Name=vvi-miR395g;ID=xxx-m0417-3
```

**HEAVILY EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION**

When fields 1, 4, and 5 are duplicated on a second line, I want to keep the duplicate line containing "Name" information at the beginning of field 9. Field 9 always begins with either "ID" or "Name". I want to remove the duplicate line where field 9 begins with "ID".

For example, the desired output would look like this:

```
chr1          mireap  precursor  6405246   6405544   .  -  .  ID=xxx-m0444;Count=3;mfe=-61.00
chr1          mireap  mature-5p  6405511   6405534   .  -  .  ID=xxx-m0444-5p;Parent=xxx-m044
chr1          mireap  precursor  6482110   6482198   .  +  .  ID=xxx-m0417;Count=105;mfe=-45.
chr1          mireap  mature-5p  6482123   6482143   .  +  .  ID=xxx-m0417-5p;Parent=xxx-m041
chr1          mireap  mature-3p  6482168   6482188   .  +  .  Name=vvi-miR395g;ID=xxx-m0417-3
```

According to 'man sort', -u outputs only the first line of "an equal run". I interpreted that as... well, if I simply sort in reverse than use -u, the "Name" containing line will be kept.

```
sort -k1,1 -k4,4n -rk5,5n file # Correctly sorts the file and the name line appears first relative to its duplicate.

sort -u -k1,1 -k4,4n -k5,5n -rk9,9 file # Runs, but still eliminates the "Name"-containing line anyway.
```

I've also thought of doing something like this:

```
sort -k1,1 -k4,4n -rk5,5n file | awk '!x[$1,$4,%5]++' FS="\t" # but haven't gotten it to work quite yet and this still wouldn't retain the desired duplicate line...
```

Ideas?

Comment: I can't see the difference between your desired output and the input - did you forget to change something?

Comment: You're right! Oops! I fixed!

Comment: Cool. And on further thought, just checking the obvious... any chance you can get away with something like `grep ' Name='`? If there are no other lines that include `Name=`, that's probably the easiest way.

Comment: Grepping Name won't work because it would exclude unique lines that don't contain Name (I still want those!). The 9th field of all unique lines actually begin with ID. Only lines where fields 1, 4, and 5 are duplicates do I want to keep the line where field 9 begins with "Name" and remove the duplicate line where field 9 begins with "ID".

Comment: Ah, so you want to remove duplicate lines from the file, using only fields 1,4,5 to check for duplicates, but in cases where there are duplicate lines (by fields 1,4,5) you want to make sure the one you keep is the one where field 9 starts with `Name=`? Sorry, I didn't figure that out.

Comment: That's ok! After your previous comment, I realized that my question wasn't initially clear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ key = $1 FS $4 FS $5; isNameLine = ($9~/^Name=/ ? 1 : 0) }
NR==FNR { if (isNameLine) hasNameLine[key]; next }
isNameLine || !(key in hasNameLine)

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
chr1          mireap  precursor  6405246   6405544   .  -  .  ID=xxx-m0444;Count=3;mfe=-61.00
chr1          mireap  mature-5p  6405511   6405534   .  -  .  ID=xxx-m0444-5p;Parent=xxx-m044
chr1          mireap  precursor  6482110   6482198   .  +  .  ID=xxx-m0417;Count=105;mfe=-45.
chr1          mireap  mature-5p  6482123   6482143   .  +  .  ID=xxx-m0417-5p;Parent=xxx-m041
chr1          mireap  mature-3p  6482168   6482188   .  +  .  Name=vvi-miR395g;ID=xxx-m0417-3
```

Comment: Please excuse the obvious newbie question- If I understand this correctly, I would create a file called tst.awk, then at the command line: "awk -f tst.awk file file"... but why does "file" occur twice?

Comment: Because your problem requires 2 passes of the input file - the first to just identify the lines that contain "Name" and then the second to produce the output which is the lines do not have a duplicate line that contains Name plus the lines that contain Name. Advice to all shell newbies - get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: I was expecting some kind of comment from you to my question [How to skip a directory in awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34018063/1983854) wink wink :D

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not entirely clear to me, 
but here is short script which will hopefully suggest a suitable implementation. It has been written with clarity rather than succinctness in mind.

First let's define "family" to mean a set of lines having the same
[$1,$4,$5] value.  Assuming you always want to keep at least one of
the "Name=" lines in a family, a global sort does make sense, as
otherwise the memory requirements could be prohibitive.

So let's start with the sort you proposed, followed by an awk
program, which you might want to tweak further depending on the
details of your requirements and additional details about the
conventions followed in the construction of the input file:

```
sort -k1,1 -k4,4n -k5,5n -rk9,9 |\
  awk '{ seen[$1,$4,$5]++ }
       $9 ~ /^Name=/ {print; next}
       seen[$1,$4,$5] > 1 { next; }
       { print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

using `sort` and pick first by `awk` idiom and depending on the lexical ordering of "Name" > "ID".

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k4,5 -k9,9r file | awk '!a[$1 FS $4 FS $5]++'

chr1          mireap  precursor  6405246   6405544   .  -  .  ID=xxx-m0444;Count=3;mfe=-61.00
chr1          mireap  mature-5p  6405511   6405534   .  -  .  ID=xxx-m0444-5p;Parent=xxx-m044
chr1          mireap  precursor  6482110   6482198   .  +  .  ID=xxx-m0417;Count=105;mfe=-45.
chr1          mireap  mature-5p  6482123   6482143   .  +  .  ID=xxx-m0417-5p;Parent=xxx-m041
chr1          mireap  mature-3p  6482168   6482188   .  +  .  Name=vvi-miR395g;ID=xxx-m0417-3
```

UPDATE:
based on comments it looks like ID part of $9 should be in key too.  Since there is no test data please verify

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k4,5 -k9,9r file 
     | awk '{match($9,/(ID=[^;]+;)/,m)} 
            !a[$1 FS $4 FS $5 FS m[1]]++'
```

Comment: This is giving an odd result on a larger, 200-line test file... In that file, there are exactly 16 duplicated lines (16 lines with ID in beginning field 9 and 16 duplicate lines with Name). I would expect that after deduplication, there would be 184 lines left in the file. Oddly, there are 182. Even though the desired "Name"-containing lines are retained and their corresponding duplicates removed, two additional "ID"-containing lines were undesireably removed.

Comment: this picks up one unique value per $1,$4,$5 key.  The removed ones should be matching to some other entries.  If you remove the `!` it will print only the duplicate lines so you can verify.

Comment: You were right! This solution works to remove duplicate lines. However, in the case where $1, $4, and $5 are duplicated, but ID's are different (ex. xxx-m0444-5p and xxx-m0444-3p), one of those ID lines is still removed. Rather, the goal was to only consider duplicates where one of them has "Name" in $9 and keep that one rather than the line with "ID" in $9. Apologies for that not being clear.